# Is there a way to display alignment lines in photoshop ?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to display alignment lines in photoshop ?

I need to see if the object in my current layer is aligned with other objects in other layers..

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the Move Tool, select the layers you need to align (either with a SHIFT or CTRL click) and then you can use the alignment tools at the top.

[image]

---

Alternatively, if you want some lines to work with. Your can press "**CTRL + R**", this will bring up the rulers. Then you can click and hold one of the rulers while dragging your mouse onto your canvas, this will create a guide with which you can align whatever you need to (either a layer or your ruler)

Relevant information:

1. While using the guides, you have the option to "snap" the guides layers, and have layers also snap to the guides, However this can get annoying sometimes if you want to turn this off, you can go to **View >>> Snap**, this will toggle the snap option.
2. "**CTRL + ;**" is the hotkey to toggle your guide(s) visibility.
3. By default your rulers may be in points, to change the unit your ruler measures with, go to: **Edit >>> Preferences >>> Units & Rulers**

Comment: Thanks. Can I automatically display the guide lines when I'm aligning the object ? In other terms, when I move an object I would like to see a guide for a potential alignment with another object in the document.

Comment: What I don't like now is that I've to create a guide and position ate it on the border of an existing object, and then use it to align my object. In some software this is displayed automatically while dragging the current object.

Comment: @Patrick View >>> Show >>> Smart Guides